# Guidelines for using Assert versus Verify

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, moq, assert, verify

I'm new to unit testing, and I'm learning how to use NUnit and Moq. NUnit provides `Assert` syntax for testing conditions in my unit tests, while Moq provides some `Verify` functions. To some extent these seem to provide the same functionality.

How do I know when it's more appropriate to use `Assert` or `Verify`?

Maybe `Assert` is better for confirming state, and `Verify` is better for confirming behavior ([Classical versus Mockist](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html))?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your assumption about Assert to confirm State and Verify to confirm behavior is correct.

You Assert a result, or a value

You Verify that a method has been called with appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 0):

From selenium point of view, Assert is a validation that if is not meet, it stops the test there and reports as fail. Instead, verify is a validation that if not meet, then continues with the test and it reports the test as failed at the end of the execution.

So, if the validations are dependent, I recommend to use assert. if validations are not dependent, then use verify.

Reference: https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/difference-between-assert-and-verify/